# Understanding event handling and callbacks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I was messing around with IndexedDB and I realised that I don't really get event handling in JavaScript.

So here's the code:

```
var request = indexeddb.open(bla, version);

request.onsuccess = function (event) {  };
```

So the open-method returns a IDBOpenDBRequest object, which, according to Mozillas site, inherits from IDBRequest, which apart from properties and methods also has event handlers, one of them being onsuccess:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBRequest.onsuccess

So on the Mozilla site, `onsuccess` is just `function () {  }`

Now, when the database was opened successfully, the `onsuccess` event fires and the appropriate event handler is called, in this case the function that I defined, but how exactly does that happen?

The request variable contains an instance of the `IDBOpenDBRequest`. So when I write `request.onsuccess = somefunction()`, am I overwriting the default function of the `IDBRequest` class?

I don't get why I can write `request.onsuccess = somefunction(event) {  }` and how the event is passed to that function.

EDIT:

```
function myObect() {
    this.open = function(a,b,c) {
        if (c > 20) {
            this.success("String");
        }
    };
};


var myrequest = new myObect();
myrequest.open(4,2,21);
myrequest.success = function (ev) {
    console.log(ev);
};
```

Comment: Well, at some point something calls `this.onsuccess(someEventObject);`, where `this` refers to the `request` object. There is no magic involved here. What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: okay, so, during the execution of the open function, this.onsuccess(eventobject) ist called... but how come that then MY code is executed? this.onsuccess(event) is already predefined in the "class" and I'm basically overwriting it, aren it?When I write an object and give it, say, this.test = function (item) { console.log(item); }, someone who instantiates that object cant just go: this.test = function (item) { alert("item); };

Comment: Yes they can. Properties are writable by default. If the have a reference to the object, they can do whatever they want with it.

Comment: In my head Im picturing something like the code in my edit, but thats obsiously wrong... how exactly is that implemented?

Comment: You'd have to assign to `success` **before** `open` is called.

Comment: nice one, thanx!! It actually works now :D But how come that in the case of indexed db I call the open function first?

Comment: Opening the connection to the process is probably an asychronous process so the `onsuccess` function would be called in the next tick of the event loop, after it was already set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a similar api, you can do something like:

```
function open(a, b, c) {
    var request = {};

    if(c > 20) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if(typeof request.success === "function") {
                request.success("String");
            }
        }, 1);
    }

    return request;
}

var myrequest = open(4, 2, 21);
myrequest.success = function(ev) {
    console.log(ev);
};
```

Here, `setTimeout` is asynchronous so the callback function is not executed immediately. When any asynchronous task is run in JavaScript, the currently executing code will run to completion before any callback is called. So `success` is guaranteed to be set before `request.success` called.

The Indexed DB `open` call similarly runs an asynchronous task, and then dispatches events when it is finished which will eventually call your callback function.

Comment: very nice! thanx a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

> I overwriting the default function of the IDBRequest-class

Looks like there is no default behavior, so you just set up your own func.